# SaltStack: Do ... if group "foo" exists on remote-host

Tags: salt-stack

How can I implement a condition bases on the fact that the remote-host a group called "foo" or not.

My use case: If there is a group called "foo" on the remote-host, then I need to add a user to it. If the group does not exist, then nothing needs to be done.

Is this possible with SaltStack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Jinja renderers](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html) in your salt states file and mix with salt.states.user.present.
(Update) .  you can use an salt override modules [pw_group](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pw_group.html)

```
{% if salt['group.info']("foo") %}
add new user if foo group found:
    user.present:
        - name: foouser
{% endif %}
```

There is  [more override modules](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/index.html#module-provider-override)  that you may use.

Comment: I'd recommend using `salt['group.info']('foo')` to test for the group existence. That will make the function work cross platform.

Comment: @Utah_Dave `salt['group.info']('foo')` looks great. Where can I find more about it in the docs? My favorite search engine returned no matching results.

Comment: @guettli right here:  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.groupadd.html#salt.modules.groupadd.info

Comment: @Utah_Dave and where are the docs that tell me that I can access the module method `salt.modules.groupadd.info` via `salt['group.info']`? The answer of mootmoot shows that I am not the only one who is not aware of this. Is this a general rule? Can I access every module like this `salt.modules.thisdoesnotmatter.modulename.methodname` via `salt[modulename.methodname]`?

Comment: @guettli : I just dig into the source code using fgrep. Then I find out it is an modules override , by pw_group . Something new to me. :-D I will edit Utah_dave answer and please mark his answer as answered.

Comment: If you look in the docs here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.group.html#module-salt.modules.group   you'll see a list of modules that Salt will load as the `group` execution module depending on the OS.  If you look in the code for the module you'll see a `__virtualname__` variable that will tell you what Salt will load the module  as.

Comment: `if salt['group.info']("foo") == "foo"` is the `== "foo"` part needed? Why not `if salt['group.info']("foo")`?

Comment: @guettli : you can do that too. I write it that way just to make the statement looks clearer.

Comment: == 'foo' won't work in 2017.7.2, I've edited the answer. Without the == it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the user on the system and add the user to certain groups only if the groups exist, the `user.present` state has an `optional_groups` option that will do that.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.user.html#salt.states.user.present

Comment: I just check out "optional_groups", it say : A list of groups to assign the user to, pass a list object. If a group specified here does not exist on the minion, the state will silently ignore it. 
So to my understanding, this is just put user under "foo" group if it exists,  even "foo" group doesn't exists, user.present still create the user.

Comment: That is correct, @mootmoot, it will still create the user.