# How to check if a remote user exists on a SaltStack state

Tags: salt-stack

I'm writing a SaltStack state, and I need to know if a remote user exists to do or don't do something.

I need something like this:

```
{% if user foo exists %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```

I've tried with user.present, user.absent, but nothing of this does what I need.

Someone have done this, but with remote groups: [SaltStack: Do ... if group "foo" exists on remote-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298827/saltstack-do-if-group-foo-exists-on-remote-host)

Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the user 'foo' exists with the following code:

```
{% set all_users = salt['user.list_users']() %}
{% if 'foo' in all_users %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Salt have module to list **All users** or to get **User info**

you can use it in the same way as they did in the *groups post*

for the module that lists user's in remote system please refer:

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.useradd.html#salt.modules.useradd.list_users

Comment: It's the way to go. Yet your answer would be better with a working example, than just linking to the docs.